# How to pass table name in read_sql_query

Tags: python, sql, pandas

i'm trying to create a function for this code:

```
db_path = dmttools.paths.payments_db

try:
    engine = dmttools.database.access_engine(db_path)
    access_zeroDollar = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM `Site Visit Fees-Zero Amount`", engine)
    logger.info('Read.')
except Exception as e:
    logger.error('Error reading database.')
    logger.error(e)
    raise e
finally:
    engine.dispose()
```

running this block works fine, problem is...I run multiple times and want to create a function to clean up my script. When I convert to this function:

```
def read_database(logger, db_path, table, df_name):
logger = dmttools.util.DefaultLogger(logger)
logger.info('Reading existing database...')

sq = "SELECT * FROM {}"
    
try:
    engine = dmttools.database.access_engine(db_path)
    df_name = pd.read_sql_query(sq.format(table), engine)
    logger.info('Read.')
except Exception as e:
    logger.error('Error reading database.')
    logger.error(e)
    raise e
finally:
    engine.dispose()
```

and call the function like this:

```
read_database('Zero Dollar Fee Aging Report', dmttools.paths.payments_db, 'Site Visit Fees-Zero Amount', 'access_test')
```

I receive this error:

```
ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in FROM clause. (-3506) (SQLExecDirectW)')
[SQL: SELECT * FROM Site Visit Fees-Zero Amount]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/f405)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change this:

```py
sq = "SELECT * FROM {}"
```

to this:

```py
sq = "SELECT * FROM `{}`"
```

If you don't, the table name won't be quoted, and it will only associate the first word of "Site Visit Fees-Zero Amount" with the table name, leaving it with extra words. That causes a syntax error.

As a side note, you may want to consider not using spaces inside your table names.

Comment: when I update to this I now get this error: DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('HY000', '[HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in query. Incomplete query clause. (-3003) (SQLExecDirectW)')
[SQL: SELECT * FROM 'Site Visit Fees-Zero Amount']
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/dbapi)

Comment: @MikeMann Note that there is a difference between `\`` and `'`.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try by formatting the table outside the function and then access the table within the function

```sql
sq = "SELECT * FROM {}"
qry = sql.format(*dict(table=table_name))
```

And within the function call the formatted variable

```sql
df_name = pd.read_sql_query(qry, connection)
```

Comment: when I attempt this, the qry line give me this error: IndexError: Replacement index 0 out of range for positional args tuple

Comment: @MikeMann remove one asterisk before dict then give a shot